# Get expanded JS source from stack trace in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, when a Javascript error occurs, you can choose to breakpoint on errors and view exactly where the error came from in the source. Then, you can click the {} button on the bottom-left to expand the source code if it's been minified onto one line.

Now, I get dumps of stack traces from actual production users whenever they hit an error. They look like this:

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
>
> c@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:89879
>   $apply@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:13:698
>   http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:14:6848
>   dispatch@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:2:27867
>   handle@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:2:24604
>   setAttribute@attr@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:2:21147
>   access@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:1:28433
>   attr@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:2:17793
>   $set@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:15493
>   http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:14:682
>   http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:15546
>   forEach@[native code]
>   s@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:11:35483
>   $set@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:15523
>   http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:14390
>   $digest@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:91816
>   $apply@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:13:773
>   http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:13:5948
>   o@http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:11:48586
>   http://www.example.com/js/application.731658e4b865.js:12:176

My question is: How can I get that same functionality from this stack trace dump and view it in the source? I know you can press CMD+O and open files to a particular line/column number, but can this be done programmatically?